# ComboBox with a gridview/table Component

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Good day

I am trying to populate a combobox in C# (WinForms) with a `list<objects>`.
However I want to display the combobox values a table of type `list<objects>`

[image: Example Image]

To link one object to the combobox works well, but linking a table or gridview or matrix as dropdown components to the combobox does not seem possible with the standard C# components.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the standard C# combobox component. or does one require third party components.
If third party components is required, does any one know of any open source/community components which are capable of doing this.

Comment: Specify the GUI framework to use. Is it WinForms, WPF, Xamarin?..

Comment: Sorry, the GUI framework is WinForms